# File input for Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: java, file, input, graph-theory, dijkstra

I am having trouble figuring out how to read an input file with java. The file has the following format:

```
u1 v1 w1
u2 v2 w2
...
um vm wm
-1
source
```

Each 3-tuple denotes an edge, which is specified by its source-vertex, its destination-vertex, and its weight (example: newyork boston 30). The description of the graph is terminated by a “flag”, the integer -1. A string follows this flag; this string is the name of the source vertex for the Dijkstra shortest-path algorithm. That is, you are to determine and print out the shortest path from this source vertex to every other vertex in the graph.
Here is my current work.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {

    public final String name;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;

    public Vertex(String argName) {
        name = argName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

}

class Edge {
    public final Vertex target;
    public final double weight;

    public Edge(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight) {
        target = argTarget;
        weight = argWeight;
    }
}

public class Dijkstra {
    public static void computePaths(Vertex source) {
        source.minDistance = 0.;
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
        vertexQueue.add(source);

        while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

            // Visit each edge exiting u
            for (Edge e : u.adjacencies) {
                Vertex v = e.target;
                double weight = e.weight;
                double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
                if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
                    vertexQueue.remove(v);

                    v.minDistance = distanceThroughU;
                    v.previous = u;
                    vertexQueue.add(v);

                }

            }
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target) {
        ArrayList<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
            path.add(vertex);

        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }

    public String[] readFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        String line = "";
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            line = line.concat(input.nextLine());
        }
        String[] graph = line.split("");
        return graph;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        final String TEST = "/TestInput.txt";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(TEST));
        String line = "";
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            line = line.concat(input.nextLine());
        }
        String[] graph = line.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(graph[i]);
        }

        Vertex[] verts = new Vertex[graph.length];
        Edge[] edges = new Edge[graph.length];
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex("");
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex("");
        Vertex source = new Vertex("");
        int count = 0;

        outerloop: for (int i = 0; i < (graph.length); i++) {

            if (graph[i].equals("-1")) {
                // do algorithm initialization here w/ source
            }
            if (i == 0) {
                verts[i] = new Vertex(graph[i]);
                count++;
            } else {
                innerloop: for (int j = count; j >= 0; j--) {
                    if (i / 3 == 0) {

                        if (graph[i].equals(verts[j].toString())) {
                            break innerloop;
                        } else if (j == 0) {
                            verts[count] = new Vertex(graph[i]);
                            v1 = verts[count];
                            count++;
                        }
                    }

                    if (i / 3 == 1) {

                        if (graph[i].equals(verts[j])) {
                            break innerloop;
                        } else if (j == 0) {
                            verts[count] = new Vertex(graph[i]);
                            v2 = verts[count];
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (i / 3 == 2) {

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < verts.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(verts[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

So my only problem is how to get from the given .txt file format to a graph. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am trying to do this in java.

Comment: Can you please link the file or give a short but complete sample of it?

Comment: Your code looks like it should probably work; what exactly is the intended purpose of line.split("")?  Also, you may wish to call input.close() after you're finished with the scanner.  What results are you getting now?

Comment: I think it's strange your edge has only one vertex.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to parse the file data. For each tuple, if the source vertex hasn't been created, create it, otherwise find it in the pre-existing graph -- create a search function. Do the same for the target vertex. Next, create an edge with a weight equal to the third token in the tuple, and add the target vertex to the edge. Finally, add the edge to the adjacency list of the source vertex.

For the previously mentioned search function, you can implement something that can search through each vertex of the graph starting from any vertex. Recursion will be necessary.

```
public static Vertex search(Vertex src, String name);
```

A simpler solution is to keep a list of all the vertices you create as your constructing the graph and search through that.

```
public static Vertex search(List<Vertex> vertices, String name);
```

When your done constructing the graph and you have the name of the vertex where Dijkstra's algorithm will begin, you can use the search function to get a reference to the vertex.

```
Dijkstra.computePath(search(vertices, startVertexName));
```

And, that's it. Here's an example of how to parse your file data:

```
List<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
String src = 
    "Pittsburgh Philadelphia 323 "+
    "Pittsburgh Ohio 125 "+
    "Ohio Philadelphia 400 "+
    "-1 Ohio";
            //new Scanner(new File(fileName));
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(src); 
String src, target;
int weight;
while(scnr.hasNext())
{
    src = scnr.next();
    if(src.equals("-1"))
        break;
    else {
        target = scnr.next();
        weight = scnr.nextInt();
    }
    //call search(), implement logic in addToGraph()
    addVertexToGraph(src, target, weight, vertices);    
}   
String startVertexName = scnr.next();
scnr.close();
```

Note that [Scanner.next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) returns the next token separated by white space (the default delimiter), so your file data must be formatted that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shot:

```
/**
 * Read the file using provided filename, construct vertices etc.
 * 
 * @param fileName name of the file to read.
 * @return true if everything is OK
 * @throws FileNotFoundException if file is not found or not readable
 */
public boolean readFile(final String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    final Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    boolean result = false;

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        final String line = line = input.nextLine();
        if ("-1".equals(line)) {
            // end of data
            if (input.hasNext()) {
                final String nameOfTheSource = input.next();
                // TODO: do something with nameOfTheSource
                result = true;
            } else {
                // bad input format: there should be something after -1
            }
        } else {
            final String Scanner vert = new Scanner(line);

            try {
                final String sourceName = vert.next();
                final String targetName = vert.next();
                final int weight = vert.nextInt(); // assuming int for weight
                // TODO: create Vertices and Edge here
            } catch (final NoSuchElementException ex) {
                // bad input format for "line"!
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Not tested.

Comment: There is something like what you are trying to do at: https://gist.github.com/artlovan/a07f29e16ab725f8077157de7abdf125

Answer (score 0):

{`import Stack.Dijkstra;
{`import java.io.File;
{`import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
{`import java.util.Scanner;

{`public class App {
    {`public static void main(String[] args) throws {`FileNotFoundException {
        {`Vertex v1 = new Vertex("A");
        {`Vertex v2 = new Vertex("B");
        {`Vertex v3 = new Vertex("C");

```
    {`v1.addNeighbour(new Edge(1, v1, v2));
    {`v1.addNeighbour(new Edge(10, v1, v2));
    {`v2.addNeighbour(new Edge(1, v2, v3));

    {`Dijkstra dijkstra = new Dijkstra();
    {`dijkstra.computePath(v1);

    {`System.out.println(dijkstra.getShortestPathTo(v3));
    {`final String test = "X:\\neon3\\eclipse\\TestInput.txt";
    {`Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(test));
    {`String line = "";
    {`while (input.hasNext()) {
        {`line = line.concat(input.nextLine());
    }
    {`String[] graph = line.split(" ");

    {`for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
        {`System.out.println(graph[i]);
    }
}
```

}`}